# How many github ssh keys do I need for a small dev team?

Tags: git, ssh, github

I'm confused by the concept of SSH keys when it comes to using a remote repository hosted by GitHub. I generated the keys as instructed in http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ , but now that I have multiple devs pushing into the repo, I'm not clear if we're all to share one single SSH key or if we all need to generate an individual key per-machine and use that?

Could someone kindly clarify that for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An **SSH key** is used for the **user** to be authenticated and identified into **GitHub**.

It is common that, for every different device a user uses to access GitHub, he generates a different ssh-key and register/link it to his GitHub's account.

When you control a project, you control access and permissions based on **users**, and not **SSH keys**.

So, when you (as a user) setup your git environment you can create only one ssh-key for each machine you would like to give permission to your GitHub's account.

---

Update:

[Github now recommends using HTTPS instead of SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended) but everything in this answer remains valid if you replace all **SSH key** references above by [Github's Personal Access Tokens](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/)

Comment: As a user, you are not limited to one SSH key. In general, though, you probably don't need more than one.

Answer (score 6):

Use a key per developer - each dev should generate their own key. This gives you a better indication of who is committing to the repo, and means that you can revoke a developer's commit rights if/when they leave the company. Otherwise they could just copy the shared key, and you would have to re-issue a new one every time you needed to change access rights.

Comment: This is messy.  As the above answer says you manage **users** not keys.  Let those users manage their own keys, there is absolutely no reason for you to generate their keys.

Comment: @Tekkub updated the wording to reflect this. I didn't mean for him to create a key to give to each user, more that each dev should have their own key.

Comment: Better, but the distinction still should be made that they should be managing these users via collaborators or teams, not handling keys directly.