# ssh-key used by git Android Studio

Tags: git, github, ssh, android-studio, ide

I need to connect to an organization, and therefore need to provide a public ssh-key. However, I am unsure which ssh-key is in use by Android Studio. 
I find myself confused because of the various ssh-options in Android Studio.

Does it simply use the only one generated by my current git-installation?

Pictures added for illustration. These files seem to correspond, and were created upon installation of the GitHub windows-client, but according to GitHub itself, has never been utilized.

[Local ssh-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qx0d.png)

[ssh-file on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKydv.png)

ex. /users/$name/.ssh/github_rsa.pub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A device has only one ssh-key for authenticating with GitHub.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419934/how-many-github-ssh-keys-do-i-need-for-a-small-dev-team)

So in this case, I needed to use the key generated by my GitHub-client, which authed all other programs using git from this client.

Answer (score 19):

For Mac users having trouble with ssh keys, I had to switch Android Studio to my "Native" SSH executable. Then it worked. See screenshot.

[image: Set AS to use native]

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.