# Android-Studio git over ssh

Tags: android, git, ssh

I got a git-server on my Raspberry Pi with gitweb as webinterface.

Its working so far.

Now I want to connect via Android Studio with the built-in ssh to it.

My project dir is :

```
/home/git/straff.git
```

I'll connect with this command from Android Studio:

```
:ssh:git@192.168.178.21:/straff
```

Android Studio is giving me this when I test the connection:

```
Cannot access /straff/CVSROOT
```

I am using password auth for it. I can access from command line tools to my repo...

Why Android Studio cant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can access from command line tools to my repo...
>   Why Android Studio cant?

Your error is you are trying to access 192.168.178.21:/straff which is /straff on that machine. Either provide the full path like below or use this one

```
:ssh:git@192.168.178.21:straff
```

Old post:

You can try to specify the full path to Android Studio:

```
:ssh:git@192.168.178.21:/home/git/straff
```

> I am using password auth for it.

That means the ssh connection doesn't use a private/public (`~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`) key.

A good tutorial to follow with Android Studio is the one titled "[How to push to a remote Git repository over SSH with private/public key authentication using Android Studio](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-push-to-a-remote-git-repository-over-ssh-with-privatepublic-key-authentication-using-android-studio/)".

Comment: `Welcome to Git (version 1.9.5-preview20150319)
git@192.168.178.21's password:
Authenticated to 192.168.178.21 ([192.168.178.21]:22).
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l


Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by applicable law.` commes, it hangs there. when I use "test connection" he always asks me for the password, again and again and

Comment: @Piet so ssh itself does work from command line, but not from Android Studio?

Comment: @Piet are you in native ssh in Android Studio? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28553240/6309). Also, you can try and follow https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-push-to-a-remote-git-repository-over-ssh-with-privatepublic-key-authentication-using-android-studio/

Comment: with the londonappdev tutorial it works now, thank you

Comment: @Piet Great. Was there a setting in particular which made the difference? I have added the link to the tutorial in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I cant say, I deleted all .git folders and did it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, should the URL be like:
    ssh://git@192.168.178.21/straff

I had problems with setting ssh key. I solved it by creating id_rsa -titled file under .ssh-directory (under user home-dir) and putting my RSA-stuff into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the remote git repository, which you want to check out, and you have a private key, then the instructions on https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-push-to-a-remote-git-repository-over-ssh-with-privatepublic-key-authentication-using-android-studio/ might help to some extent, but they are for older version of Android Studio and they are too complicated.

What you need to do (especially when you start from scratch) is:

1. Ensure that your key is an OpenSSH key, and that it's a private key (not a public key). This is where the above mentioned instructions are misleading - they point to the key in supposedly Putty format (the .ppk file), and this doesn't work. If you have a Putty key, use Putty's puttygen.exe tool to export the private key in OpenSSH format.
2. Create the `config` file as described in those instructions. I.e.

   1. create the text file named `config` in `.ssh` subdirectory of your user directory. In my case the path would be C:\Users\Eugene.ssh\config.
   2. Put the following to this file:

> Host  my-host.com
>
> HostName    my-host.com
>
> Port        22
>
> IdentityFile  C:\Users\Eugene.ssh\my-private-key-for-my-host.openssh

(the original instructions include indentation of lines 2-4, but I couldn't add any indentation here).

3. Use `Checkout Project From Version Control` menu item in Android Studio's welcome screen to initiate GIT checkout.
4. Use the following settings during checkout (curly brackets contain the values which you replace with yours):

> Git Repository URL: {projectalias}@{my-host.com}:base/{projectname}
>
> Parent directory: eg. "z:\Projects" The path which must exist, and in which the new project is created
>
> Project directory: eg. "myproject". The directory with this name will be created in Parent directory, so the files will be checked out to Parent_directory\Project_directory, eg. "z:\Projects\myproject".